# Argument of type '{ message: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'any[]'

Tags: angular, firebase

I am working on a project from the LinkedIn learning library using FireBase.  I have been able to figure out a few of the updates from the movie, but I am stuck on one.
I get the error

> Argument of type '{ message: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'any[]'.
>     Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'message' does not exist in type 'any[]'.
>   from this code:

```
   export class AppComponent {
 items: AngularFireList<any[]>;
 msg  =  '';

 constructor(public af: AngularFireDatabase) {
  this.items = af.list('/messages');
 }
 send(chatMsg: string) {
   this.items.push({ message: chatMsg });
   this.msg = '';
 }
    }
```

The error seems to be from `this.items.push({message: chatMsg });`

I have imported both the AngularFireDatabase and AngularFireList from '@angular/fire/database';  So I am not sure what the issue is.  I am trying to learn Angular and am a bit lost right now.

Comment: convert `` items: AngularFireList<any[]>`` to `` items: AngularFireList<any>``

Answer (score 0):

`AngularFireList` expects a generic argument that represents a single item in the list. Currently you are specify that each item in the list is an `any[]`.

You probably want the type definition to be `AngularFireList<any>` instead.

Comment: Thanks, that cleared up the original issue, now I am getting this error in the console: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Comment: @Jim Please open a new question for a different issue and choose an accepted answer if it helped you solve your original problem. Post the link to your new question here and I will take a look :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example [in documentation here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md#deleting-the-entire-list), you need to :

```
items: AngularFireList<any>;
```

in stead of `items: AngularFireList<any[]>;`

Comment: Thanks @nircraft, based on the example I was able to make this work for me.